# How to load block on link click with AJAX framework?

Tags: 7, ajax

I have tried in my custom module:

Declaring a path for Ajax callback

```
function custom_menu() {

  $items['ajax-block/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Ajax test callback',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'ajax_link_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

now the callback itself

```
/**
 * Callback ajax
 */
function ajax_link_callback($from_cid, $mode = NULL) {

  if ($mode != 'ajax') {
    drupal_set_message('Turn Javascript');
    drupal_goto(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '<front>');
  }

  $commands[] = ajax_command_html('.region-content', some_func());

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

I have a few manually created links:

```
<a class="use-ajax" href="/ajax-block/1/nojs">link1</a>
<a class="use-ajax" href="/ajax-block/2/nojs">link2</a>
<a class="use-ajax" href="/ajax-block/3/nojs">link3</a>
```

Now I need such functionality - when I press link1 - block1 loads content in to .region-content, when I click link2 - block2 and etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your missing the ajax_deliver command

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_html('.region-content', some_func());
$page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
ajax_deliver($page);
```

Comment: How can i show different content on different links?

Comment: You will need to create functions to return HTML loading a block or whatever, it would replace with some_func()

Comment: The call to `ajax_deliver()` is not necessary, since that is set as delivery callback; this means Drupal will call it automatically, before returning the page to the browser.